# How to display daily total in this foreach?

Tags: php, sql-server, foreach

I've made a function that queries a MSSQL database to get a list of daily totals by rep. I group them into weeks with an ISO week number which then shows the days. At the end of the week I produce a total thus:

[image]

You can see from the image that each week is separated automatically, then each row has the day, rep and total data in it. Where I've put the red line, I'd like to be able to total up the day with an additional row, but can't quite figure out how to do so, I'm guessing with an additional nested `foreach`?

Here's the current function that produces the above:

```
function getWorkInByDay()
{
    global $db;
    $data = '';

    // Build query
    $q = mssql_query("SELECT DATEPART(isowk,Datedb) AS 'Week', DAY(Datedb) AS 'Day', Ref1 AS 'Rep', SUM(PriceEst) AS 'Total', Datedb AS 'Date' FROM MainJobDetails WHERE MONTH(Datedb) = " . date('m') . " AND YEAR(Datedb) = " . date('Y') . " GROUP BY DATEPART(isowk,Datedb), DAY(Datedb), Ref1, Datedb",$db);

    $weeks = array();
    while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $weeks[$r['Week']][] = $r;
    }

    foreach ($weeks as $w => $rs) {
        $t = 0;
        $data .= "<table class='data full-width'>";
        $data .= "<thead><tr><td colspan='3'>". date('F'). " - Week ".$w."</td></tr></thead>";
        foreach ($rs as $r) {
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $data .= "<td>".date('l',strtotime($r['Date']))."</td>";
            $data .= "<td>".$r['Rep']."</td>";
            $data .= "<td>£".number_format($r['Total'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            $data .= "</tr>";
            $t += $r['Total'];
        }
        $data .= "<tr><td></td><td></td><td><strong>Total: £".number_format($t, 2, '.', ',')."</strong></td></tr>";
        $data .= "</table>";
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use simple pivoting function to show week as column as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [with rollup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) group by modifier to get a totals row for each group by clause